# PHP based contact form submission on godaddy

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have created a basic contact form with php script to send an email if some one submits a form.

I tried the below ways:

> 1. Giving the FROM email as emailid@mydomainname.com
> 2. Giving the FROM email as emailid@gmail.com

```
    <form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactform">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-line">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername">Your name</label>
                        <input name="name"  type="text" class="form-control" id="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Address</label>
                        <input name="email"  type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" >
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telephone">Mobile No.</label>
                        <input name="phone"  type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for ="description"> Message</label>
                        <textarea  name="comment" class="form-control" id="description" style="background-color:transparent;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-default submit"> Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>
```

**PHP** segment

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1

if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

//recipient - replace your email here
$to = 'emailid1@hostedwebsite.com'; 
//sender - from the form
$from = 'emailid2@hostedwebsite.com';   

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Message for WebTweet from ' . $name;    
$message = 'Name: ' . $name . '<br/><br/>
           Email: ' . $email . '<br/><br/>      
           Message: ' . nl2br($comment) . '<br/>';

//send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

//if the errors array has values
} else {
//display the errors message
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
echo '<a href="index.html">Back</a>';
exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
}

?>
```

Please help me in identifying the issue as i am new to php programming and hosting.

I have hosted the form and PHP in goDaddy.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you get an error message? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont see any call happening to php part.
I don't get any error message.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to `contact.php` directly?

Comment: `$_REQUEST['name']`, `$_REQUEST['email']`, etc., etc. You don't need ternary if get/post thing.

Comment: Ah, goDaddy is well known for problems like this...ask on their forums. and try with input type=submit, not with ordinary button...

Comment: Thanks @sinisake it worked with input type=submit